# Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "xi:include"

Tags: xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

appender/console.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} log4j2-dev %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
</Console>
```

log4j2.dev.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <Appenders>
        <xi:include href="appender/console.xml" />
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I write a simple log4j2 config(above) which use `xmlns:xi`. The error output is

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
2015-11-14 16:19:34,348 ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "xi:include"
2015-11-14 16:19:34,376 ERROR Unable to locate appender Console for logger
```

But if i merge `appender/console.xml` and `log4j2.dev.xml` and use the merged one. The error is gone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} log4j2-dev %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

I googled a lot. But can't find a solution to solve it. Please help.

Comment: You might have to activate an option to tell log4j to be XInclude-aware. Try adding `-Dorg.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration= org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeParserConfiguration` when running your app (assuming Xerces is the XML parser being used).

Comment: @potame thanks, you are right.